# I have installed Gnome3 and now can't login. How can I login from console?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I have installed Gnome3 from the Gnome3 PPA and after restart NO window interface is appearing. I have installed LXDE, Gnome Classic and Unity 2D. When I've installed Gnome3 I was in the Unity 2D session and I think that this has been broken and now doesn't let me to login.
After boot I enter in safe mode and from the console I want to change the log in environment to LXDE and after that to give Logout and choose Gnome3.
How can I enter in LXDE (or directly in Gnome3) from console/terminal?

Btw gdm start gives me an error!

Answer (score 1):

in the description of the ppa it says:

"This PPA is EXPERIMENTAL and MAY BREAK YOUR SYSTEM. There is no downgrade process"

Gnome 3 is currently not supported by ubuntu, I don't know about the downgrade part but you can try removing the ppa with ppa-purge :

sudo apt-get intall ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

Comment: and reinstall gnome-desktop, or ubuntu-desktop or other enviroments.

Comment: Didin't remember adding the gnome 3 ppa removes unity :P

Comment: it doesn't remove unity, but you know ... unity uses gtk2 and gnome 3 uses gtk3, errors might happen.